# How easy is it to find a temporary job in Brisbane as a foreign university student?

Tags: australia, work, working-holiday, brisbane, queensland

I am looking to travel to Brisbane, AU for a period of 3-6+ months. I can obtain a work-holiday visa; but how easy is it for someone to make it a working holiday, especially without prior experience and without a university degree?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about job hunting

Comment: Questions about working holidays are Allowed(tm). http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/working-holiday-good-au-pair-bad-expat-bad-why-not-set-the-bar-at-one-year-re/1644

Comment: @jpatokal he's not saying it's off topic because of the working holiday - working holiday visa TRAVEL questions are permitted.  He's saying it's off topic because it's about job hunting, not travel.

Comment: @Berecz_Fereng - in advance is difficult, many of my friends who are here on working holidays tried before they came, but found it FAR easier to pick up work on the ground.  When you arrive, stay in a hostel, they'll give you all the advice you need for working holiday work - many of them may even know of jobs for you.

Comment: @MarkMayo Questions about finding temporary employment while traveling is totally OK in my book, and we even have a tag for it: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-holiday

Comment: @jpatokal There are 2 questions in the post 1 of whether its possible to find a job in Brisbane on a WH visa and 2 how to do it.  First questions answer is basically yes it is possible which isn't particularly helpful and 2nd question is off topic since it is about methods for job hunting in Brisbane.  While it may not be ideal for Expats I would venture to say it might be more helpful there rather then here since Brisbane job hunting tips are more helpful for expats anyway

Comment: @jpatokal I couldn't see any questions on how to find a job. Rathe limitations of the Working Holiday programs by various countries

Comment: @Karlson Are you serious?  A backpacker looking for temporary unskilled jobs during a 3-month working holiday is not an "expat" by any definition.

Comment: @jpatokal You're misreading the comment.

Comment: I have to agree that if this question is about looking for a job as a backpacker/gap year/working holiday traveller then it's definitely on topic. Otherwise we would be saying things like "This question is off-topic because it's about car rental." Stuff that travellers do while travelling that they have to ask questions is on-topic.

Comment: Does it have to be in Brisbane, or are you happy to travel within Queensland and NE NSW?

Comment: I changed the question to one of "working holiday" and vote to reopen in its current form.

Comment: It's still more that it's way broad, 'how easy is it' is going to be subjective... :(

Comment: As Mark mentioned, in it's current form, it would still be opinion based...how "easy" it is, how does one answer that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't worry**.  Finding temporary unskilled jobs in Australia is easy, the economy is booming and Australians don't want to do them so hostels, cafes, restaurants, ski resorts, farms etc rely quite heavily on cheap, seasonal backpacker/working holiday labor.

As Mark says, the easiest thing is to simply ask around at your hostel after arrival, but also take a look at [Gumtree](http://www.gumtree.com.au) to get an idea of the type of jobs and wages on offer.

Comment: I work in a backpacker hostel in Bondi Beach in Sydney where hundreds of foreign backpackers come to look for work. I can say that even though Australia did not go into recession after the Global Financial Crisis in 2008 that the number of jobs has definitely decreased and the number of people on working holiday visas giving up and going home early has definitely increased. Skilled jobs and hard work jobs are your best bet. Hostel/cafe/restaurant jobs are not as easy as before. Fruit picking is always available but not for everybody. Brisbane is less touristy so fewer seasonal.

Comment: `simply ask around at your hostel after arrival` I noticed when I travel on a holiday to hostels I (and other tourists too) often ask the staff there for advice on food/locations/etc, therefore not sure if they would be willing to accept somebody fresh off the boat without much knowledge of the area? And even if they would, feels a bit embarrassing not to be able to answer questions from the tourists (not sure what's the right way to deal with that).